# Correct way to calculating interest accrued with leap year

Tags: loans

Principal is $119,654.7
compounding semi annually
Disbursal Date is 11/25/2015
Initial Payment is 3/15/2016
Interest Rate 9.1%

In this case 
    - there is 36 days in 365
    - there is 75 days in 366
    - Total of 111 days

How should interest Accrued be calculated?

Example 1.

```
 InterestAccrued = (((1 + 0.091/2)^2 )^ (36/365 + 75/366)  - 1 ) * 119654.7
                 = 3276.27
```

Or should the interest accrued be split and added together like below

Example 2.

```
 InterestAccrued = (((1 + 0.091/2)^2 )^ (36/365)  - 1 ) * 119654.7
                 = 1054.84895
 InterestAccrued += (((1 + 0.091/2)^2 )^ (75/366)  - 1 ) * 119654.7
                 = 3256.86
```

Or should the interest balance be added on to the balance before calculating interest accrued

Example 3

```
 InterestAccrued = (((1 + 0.091/2)^2 )^ (36/365)  - 1 ) * 119654.7
                 = 1054.84895
 InterestAccrued = (((1 + 0.091/2)^2 )^ (75/366)  - 1 ) * (119654.7 + InterestAccrued )
                 = 3276.27
```

Comment: The finance companies with which I have experience have used either a fixed 360 or 365 day year, so they ignore leap years.

Comment: I wish that was my case, their product is Actual/Actual.

Comment: The correct answer is example 2 then

Answer (score 1):

In an actual/actual loan, your example number 2 is correct. The interest is accrued at a daily rate in 2015 that is different than 2016, so it needs to be calculated separately and added together.